# how to "regex" all options in select menu

Tags: php, regex, html-select

The sample data is this:

```html
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UrunListesi$ctrl0$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl0_StokBoyut">
<option value="900061_50x80">50x80 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900067_60x110">60x110 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900037_70x140">70x140 Stok:0</option>
<option value="356593_80 T.Yolluk">80 T.Yolluk Stok:2</option>
<option value="356552_80x150">80x150 Stok:23</option>
</select>
```

With the following code I can capture only one data:

```
$regex_select = '/<select name="ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolder1\$UrunListesi\$ctrl([0-9]{1,2})\$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl([0-9]{1,2})_StokBoyut">(.*?)/msi';
preg_match_all($regex_select, $get, $d);
```

How can I capture all  data to "SIZExSIZE" (e.g 50x80 or 150x230) and "Stock: [0-9]" until the last Select.

Comment: why would you want to use regexp, when using DOMDocument would be so much easier ?

Comment: ...something something html & regex something... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9197799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `(.*)` by `([\s\S]*?)<\/select>`

so the complete regexp would be: `<select name="ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolder1\$UrunListesi\$ctrl([0-9]{1,2})\$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl([0-9]{1,2})_StokBoyut">([\s\S]*?)<\/select>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aymNDG/1/)

`.` does not match new lines so you may use `[\s\S]` instead which matches anything.

Once you have the `select` you want. Use an extra regex `value=".*?_(\d+(?:x\d+)?)">.*?Stok:(\d+)` for getting the size and stock values (first and second capturing group)

For example:

```
<?php
$re = '/<select name="ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolder1\$UrunListesi\$ctrl([0-9]{1,2})\$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl([0-9]{1,2})_StokBoyut">([\s\S]*?)<\/select>/mi';
$str = '
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UrunListesi$ctrl0$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl0_StokBoyut">
<option value="900061_50x80">50x80 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900067_60x110">60x110 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900037_70x140">70x140 Stok:0</option>
<option value="356593_80 T.Yolluk">80 T.Yolluk Stok:2</option>
<option value="356552_80x150">80x150 Stok:23</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="dontwantthis">xxxx</option>
</select>

<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UrunListesi$ctrl0$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl0_StokBoyut">
<option value="900061_50x80">50x80 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900067_60x110">60x110 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900037_70x140">70x140 Stok:0</option>
<option value="356593_80 T.Yolluk">80 T.Yolluk Stok:2</option>
<option value="356552_80x150">80x150 Stok:23</option>
</select>

';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $select) {
    print "I like this select:______________\n";
    print $select . "\n";
    print "The values are:**********\n";
    preg_match_all('/value=".*?_(\d+(?:x\d+)?)[^"]*">.*?Stok:(\d+)/', $select, $values, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        print "  - $value[1] and Stock=$value[2]\n";
    }
    print "\n\n";
}
```

See it in action [here](https://www.ideone.com/gO7SmJ).

**Result**

```
The values are:
  - 50x80 and Stock=0
  - 60x110 and Stock=0
  - 70x140 and Stock=0
  - 80 and Stock=2
  - 80x150 and Stock=23
```

Comment: Thank you.

Is there a way to extract the data in Option?

Comment: I updated my answer for adding an example on how to extract the values

Answer (score 1):

Should try with `DOMDocument` object.

```
<?php

$html = '<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UrunListesi$ctrl0$StokBoyut" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UrunListesi_ctrl0_StokBoyut">
<option value="900061_50x80">50x80 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900067_60x110">60x110 Stok:0</option>
<option value="900037_70x140">70x140 Stok:0</option>
<option value="356593_80 T.Yolluk">80 T.Yolluk Stok:2</option>
<option value="356552_80x150">80x150 Stok:23</option>
</select>';
$html  = '<html>'. $html . '</html>';

/*** a new dom object ***/
$dom = new DOMDocument();

/*** load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$pattern = '@\d+x\d+@s'; // Format: (number)x(number)
$stokPattern = '@(Stok:)\d+@s';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('option') as $row) {
    $attributeValue = $row->getAttribute('value');
    preg_match_all($pattern, $attributeValue);
    if (preg_match($pattern, $attributeValue, $match)) {
        echo $match[0] . '<br/>';
    }

    $text = $row->textContent;
    if (preg_match($stokPattern, $text, $match)) {
        echo $match[0] . '<br/>';
    }
    //echo $row->getAttribute('value') . '<br/>'; //Get value
    //echo $row->textContent . '<br/>'; // Get text
}
```

Example result:

```
50x80
Stok:0
60x110
Stok:0
70x140
Stok:0
Stok:2
80x150
Stok:23
```